How to Increase SNAT Ports for Azure App Service Plan P1v3
I am currently using an Azure App Service Plan P1v3, which hosts 11 app services. These services are integrated with a same Virtual Network (VNet) . Despite optimizing my code to close connections after use , I am still encountering SNAT port exhaustion issues. How can I increase the available SNAT ports ?
I am looking for effective ways to increase the number of available SNAT ports to prevent exhaustion and ensure reliable outbound connectivity for my app services.

You could attach a NAT gateway to your vNet:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dive-deep-into-nat-gateway-s-snat-port-behavior/
